# How to return generic Collection from a function in Java?

Tags: java, generics

So I can across this piece of code which is a demostration for generic methods in Java:

```
public static <T> T addAndReturn(T element, Collection<T> collection){
    collection.add(element);
    return element;
}

....

String stringElement = "stringElement";
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
String theElement = addAndReturn(stringElement, stringList);
```

But instead of returning the element I want to **send back the whole  collection object** . I have tried few giving return type as Collection but it is somehow not working,

```
public static <T> Collection<T> addAndReturn(T element, Collection<T> collection) {
        collection.add(element);
        System.out.println(collection);
        return collection;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        String stringElement = "stringElement";
        List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();

        ArrayList<String> strRes = addAndReturn(stringElement, strList);
        System.out.println(strRes);
    }
```

and received this error:

> Main.java:22: error: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type
>   variable(s) T exist so that Collection conforms to
>   ArrayList         ArrayList strRes =
>   addAndReturn(stringElement, strList);
>                                                ^   where T is a type-variable:
>       T extends Object declared in method addAndReturn(T,Collection) 1 error

can anyone help me with the solution ?

> code sample is from [Jenkov.com](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-generics/methods.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit, given the comments from the OP: one has to understand that `ArrayList` derives from Collection. So when the interface of a method returns `Collection<T>`, then of course, you can only assign the result to a `Collection`, but not to a List/ArrayList. The fact that you pass in a List instance isn't known. The compiler only sees that a Collection comes back!

Coming back to the first question: your code is returning the element that got added:

```
public static <T> T addAndReturn(T element, Collection<T> collection){
    collection.add(element);
    return element;
}
```

Simply change the signature and the returned thing:

```
public static <T> Collection<T> addAndReturn(T element, Collection<T> collection){
    collection.add(element);
    return collection;
}
```

Done? Not really.

As in: that isn't good practice. Returning something that came in as parameter can quickly lead to confusion for readers of your code. Confusing your readers is a *bad* thing to do.

Beyond that: the whole method is simply *bogus* itself, as callers of the method could as well just write:

```
thatCollection.add(thatElement);
```

themselves. Your method doesn't add **any** value to the above! It rather obscures things for the readers.

Why would anybody want to write:

```
addAndReturn(someX, listOfXes);
```

instead of

```
listOfXes.add(someX);
```

If the point would be to do:

```
addAndReturn(someX, listOfXes).addAndReturn(someOtherX, listOfXes);
```

You rather go:

```
listOfXes.addAll(Arrays.asList(someX, someOtherX));
```

for example. Don't invent "utilities" for things that can be dealt with using standard library calls.

Comment: Thanks @Ghostcat for your elaborate answer. The question was out of total curiosty. I just found out that I tried this but the issue was with the receiving object. I was using ArrayList<String> to get back the collection. Changing it to Collection<String> worked.
`Collection<String> strRes = addAndReturn(stringElement, strList);`
Can you add this in your answer too ?

Comment: Consider deleting no longer required comments by the way ;-)

Comment: I love your non code answers ! And I love still more your non answers : The meta of the meta ! Oh I will read it :) Hey FYI you forget to tag me in the comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
public static <T> Collection<T> addAndReturn(T element, Collection<T> collection) {
    collection.add(element);
    return collection;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It goes like in the listing below.

```
public static <T> Collection<T> addAndReturn(final T element, final Collection<T> collection) {
    collection.add(element);
    return collection;
}

@Test
public void test() {
    final String stringElement = "stringElement";
    final List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    final List<String> nextList = (List<String>) addAndReturn(stringElement, stringList);
    assertThat(nextList.get(0), is(equalTo(stringElement)));
}
```

All you have to care about is the right return parameter `Collection<T>`. Maybe you have to cast if you want it from a child class or interface like List `final List<String> nextList = (List<String>) addAndReturn(stringElement, stringList);`.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pointing to this line:

> ```
> ArrayList<String> strRes = addAndReturn(stringElement, strList);
> ```

And it is telling you (in non-Compilerese plain English) that it could not find a generic type that would allow this assignment to happen.

Your method returns a `Collection<T>` (in this case a `Collection<String>`). `Collection<String>` is not a subtype of `ArrayList<String>`, ergo, you are not allowed to assign an object of type `Collection<String>` to a field of type `ArrayList<String>`. Your method returns a `Collection<String>`, so the easiest fix is to just assign it to a field of type `Collection<String>`:

```
Collection<String> strRes = addAndReturn(stringElement, strList);
```

Alternatively, you could make use of local variable type inference (assuming you are using a current version of Java):

```
var strRes = addAndReturn(stringElement, strList);
```